# MATLAB randomization/counterbalancing issue

Tags: matlab, random

I have the following MATLAB code:

```
files = dir(fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','semjudge',bpic,'*.png')); 
nFiles = numel(files);
combos = nchoosek(1:nFiles, 2);
index = combos(randperm(size(combos, 1)), :); 
picture1 = files(index(nRep,1)).name;
picture2 = files(index(nRep,2)).name;
image1 = fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','semjudge',bpic,picture1);
image2 = fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','semjudge',bpic,picture2);
subplot(1,2,1); imshow(image1); 
subplot(1,2,2); imshow(image2);
```

It randomizes the picture files in a given directory, and presents them on the screen. However, I have two problems:

1) The number of picture files is quite large, and I want to break it up into 3 or 4 blocks for the subjects. How do I go about doing this? I can't pull them from different directories, because over the course of all the blocks I need to have every possible picture pair. I can't figure out how to get MATLAB to split this up into blocks.

2) Every time I run the program, the pictures are presented in the same order? Why does this happen? It should be completely random, right?

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't really understand what you mean by "split into blocks", but how about using different filename suffixes for each "block"?

2) No, the way you do it the (increasing) order for each column is enforced by `nchoosek` and then you just permute the rows. If you want to show two random pictures, like in the example above, you may use `randsample(nFiles, 2)`.

Comment: Well, say I have 1000 trials. That's too many in one sitting, so I want to split it up into 4 blocks of 250 trials, but counterbalanced across the blocks so I still get all 1000 original combinations. I just have no idea how to go about doing this in MATLAB.